# Why i can't import .svelte components?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, vite, sveltekit

I am having this issue recently. I can't import search.svelte file to index.svelte. Here are details.

index.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Search from "src/routes/search.svelte";
</script>

<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>

<Search/>
```

search.svelte

just an input box for demonstration purposes.

```
<input type="text">
```

here is the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'src/routes/search.svelte' imported from 'D:/VScode/Repos/Svelte-Endpoints/src/routes/index.svelte'
    at viteResolve (file:///D:/VScode/Repos/Svelte-Endpoints/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-1513d487.js:50354:25)
    at nodeImport (file:///D:/VScode/Repos/Svelte-Endpoints/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-1513d487.js:50389:15)
    at ssrImport (file:///D:/VScode/Repos/Svelte-Endpoints/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-1513d487.js:50284:20)
    at eval (/src/routes/index.svelte:7:37)
    at async instantiateModule (file:///D:/VScode/Repos/Svelte-Endpoints/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-1513d487.js:50330:9)
```

I cant understand how this happens. Its a .svelte file not some external library or something can cause an error.

Comment: Look at the error carefully. It is trying to load the module from `D:/VScode/Repos/Svelte-Endpoints/src/routes/index.svelte`. Is that path correct? Do you have that file in the VScode folder in your D drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of relative vs absolute paths.
If you have a file structure like:

```
/src/routes/index.svelte
/src/routes/Search.svelte
```

you would do

```js
import Search from './Search.svelte';
```

That said, you shouldn't have a file structure like that because all files under `src/routes` are a route, meaning you would have both `http://my-site/` and `http://my-site/Search`

It is better to put components in a different folder all togeter, for example under `src/lib/components`, if you do that SvelteKit has configured aliases by default such that you can do

```js
import Search from '$lib/components/Search.svelte';
```